# What's the probability distribution for a single entry of a random unitary (or orthogonal) matrix?

Tags: measure-theory, random-matrices, unitary-matrices, haar-measure

Consider a random $n \times n$ unitary matrix, i.e. whose probability measure is the Haar measure for $\mathrm{U}(n)$. What is the marginal probability distribution for a single element of this matrix? What about for a random orthogonal matrix?

Since the elements of a unitary matrix must have norm $\leq 1$, the probability density function must be compactly supported on $[-1, 1]$, so it can't be analytic.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274092/entries-of-haar-random-unitary-matrices) is similar but (I think) asks for the joint marginal distribution between two different entries, whereas my question is simpler and only asks for the marginal distribution for a single element.